# FOP generated PDF borders missing

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm having a strange problem with the PDF I've generated using FOP v0.94.

The borders are missing at some points. But I've given border="solid 0.5px" for all table-cells.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are most likely side-effects of anti-aliasing in Acrobat. If you disable "smooth line art" in Acrobat's preferences, the effect will most likely go away. And it probably won't appear in print in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer...! It worked...!

All this time I thought it was an issue with FOP or my code.

And yeah, it wont affect the print...